# Minimum Set Cover Algorithm: Finding Size of Optimal Cover

Tags: algorithm, optimization, np, set-theory, set-cover

The Set-Cover Problem consists of the following:

> Given:
>
> > 1. A set of Items U.
> > 2. A set of Sets S each of which contain items from U.
>
> Find the set of sets C such that:
>
> > 1. C is a subset of S.
> > 2. The sets in C contains all items in U. (at least once).
>
> Optionally, one can find the **Minimum** C, i.e where |C| is as small as possible.

[Wiki Link to Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

I understand that SCP is NP-Complete and MSCP (or Optimal SCP) is NP-Hard, and that one may use one of many techniques to find it (Greedy Algorithm, Genetic Algorithm, Artificial Neural Network).

However, I want to ask whether finding the size of C (i.e |C|) is NP-Hard too.

To show an example:

```
Given the following S:
[2 4 6], [1 3 5], [3 2 1], [5 4 6], [2 3 5]

And U being: 
1 2 3 4 5 6

A possible Set-Cover (C) is:
[2 4 6], [1 3 5], [2 3 5]

However, the Optimal Set-Cover (C) is:
[3 2 1], [5 4 6]

Thus |C|, the size of the Optimal Set-Cover is 2.
```

I want to find |C| without solving the problem.
Is this NP-Hard? If not, How can one go about finding this?

Comment: There's a misconception in the question about what NP means. It applies to decision problems, and the actual "set cover problem" is "is there a cover of size <= k?" and not "find a minimum cover".

Answer (score 3):

If you could find the size of the minimum cover in P time, then so too could you find a minimum cover in P time.

For each X in S, find the size of the minimum cover of U - X. If it's one less than the size of the minimum cover of U then you know there's a minimum cover containing X (note: a minimum cover of U - X never includes the set X). Repeat until you've found a minimum cover.

Note that the size of the cover is at most |U|, and each iteration requires |S| X's to consider, so the overall procedure is P-time if you've got a P-time way of finding the size of the minimum cover.

Comment: I'm not asking how to find the minimum cover. I'm asking whether it's possible to find the size of the minimum cover without actually finding the minimum cover.

Comment: I've shown that if you can find the size of the minimum cover in polynomial time, then you can also find a minimum cover in polynomial time, so it's no easier.